# Layout function in R

Tags: r, layout, scatter-plot

I am attempting to use the layout () function in R but am struggling to get the correct structure as I need a small plot graph along with a large 3d scatter plot in the same page. Currently the two are equal sized but are very squashed. I could allow the first graph to be reduced in size to allow more room for the larger plot, please excuse the rough diagram:

| 1 small |
|graph    |
|         |

|                         |
|     1 large scatterplot |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |

Any ideas would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The best way to understand `layout()` is to plan out in your head or on paper a matrix of cells that cover the device and allocate cells to plots.

I suspect you want something like

```
m <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,
              1,1,0,0,
              2,2,2,2,
              2,2,2,2,
              2,2,2,2,
              2,2,2,2), ncol  = 4, byrow = TRUE)
layout(m)
plot(1:10)
plot(rnorm(10000), rnorm(10000))
layout(1)
```

which gives

[image]

In this example, a `0` means the space is not used for the plot (as there is no way to create a zeroth plot, the first plot is plot 1), a `1` indicates where the first plot will go, and `2` the second plot.

You'll need to play about with dimensions of the device and/or whitespace in the margins (e.g. the top margin of each plot if you use no titles) to get more square layouts.

The `layout.show()` function may also be of use as it shows the panels with a number indicating where each plot will go. For example:

```
layout(m)
layout.show(n = 2) ## next `n` plots
```

[image]

The other addition you can make is to specify the widths & height of the *columns* and *rows* of the specified matrix, relatively or absolutely, via the `widths` and `heights` arguments.